# Как определить набор (множество) вариантов в ansible inventory?

Tags: ansible

Рефакторю [ansible inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html).

Есть хосты с похожими именами:

```
host1.datacenter-a.com
host2.datacenter-a.com
host1.datacenter-k.com
host2.datacenter-k.com
host1.datacenter-x.com
host2.datacenter-x.com
```

Номер я могу свернуть как [1:2]:

```
host[1:2].datacenter-a.com
host[1:2].datacenter-k.com
host[1:2].datacenter-x.com
```

А можно ли каким-то образом перечислить буквы, которе не являются последовательностью (даже с шагом)?

```
# все эти варианты не работают
host[1:2].datacenter-[a,k,x].com
host[1:2].datacenter-[akx].com
host[1:2].datacenter-[a|k|x].com
host[1:2].datacenter-[a:k:x].com
host[1:2].datacenter-[a k x].com
```

Comment: К сожалению группировать возможно только по диапазону. Все что приходит в голову это явно прописать [chidren группы](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#groups-of-groups-and-group-variables)

Comment: @BorysBorysenko ага, уже убедился, что вариантов пока что нет. Возможно, когда-нибудь реализуют.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В комментариях уже верно сказали, что возможности паттернов хостов ограничены диапазоном (буквы либо цифры). В принципе, на этом бы можно было и завершить вопрос, но.

Хочу указать ещё одно возможное направление решения проблемы. Можно использовать [dynamic inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html).

Наша задача сводится к тому, чтобы написать некоторый скрипт `inventory/dyn.py` на питоне, который будет выводить обычный json:

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {
      "10.1.0.10": {
        "ansible_user": "vagrant",
        "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "/home/mrtuovinen/.ssh/id_rsa",
        "ansible_port": 22
      },
      "10.1.0.11": {
        "ansible_user": "ubuntu",
        "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "/home/mrtuovinen/.ssh/id_rsa",
        "ansible_port": 22
      },
      "10.1.0.12": {
        "ansible_user": "steve",
        "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "/home/mrtuovinen/.ssh/key.pem",
        "ansible_port": 2222
      }
    }
  },
  "vagrantbox": [
    "10.1.0.10"
  ],
  "ubuntubox": [
    "10.1.0.11"
  ],
  "osxbox": [
    "10.1.0.12"
  ]
}
```

и запустить его на выполнение:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/dyn.py -l targethost my_playbook.yml
```

В скриптах уже можно использовать всю мощь регулярок, циклов, шаблонов и т.п.

Разумеется, подходит не для всех случаев  - иногда проще вручную указать хосты.

Comment: Хм, а я не знал, что в качестве источника dynamic inventory можно давать код на выполнение.

Comment: Кстати, я пришёл к выводу, что сворачивать группы - не всегда лучшее решение. Во-первых это ломает логику плагинов для подсветки синтаксиса `.ini`-файлов. Во-вторых, это навязывает определённый порядок перебора хостов, что ломает `serial: n`